# Best way to program on the GPU?

Tags: pi-4, gpu

So I have a project where over-heating and performance are crucial. So I came up with 2 ideas from the get go; Only compile a kernel without an OS and run my algorithms on the GPU.

On PC environment, I would either use Vulkan or OpenCL for such a job. The problem with OpenCL is that is not supported on raspberry pi 4B as far as I know. The problem with Vulkan is that it's a large graphics API rather than a GPU computing API and it's slower than OpenCL which defeats the whole purpose.

There is also the fact that this will be ran on an OS less hardware. I'm planning on cross compiling on my PC and adding my programs to kernels 'init' function to start and run my code indefinitely.

The question is: What is the definitive way to make GPU calculations? I've heard about SYCL but I'm fairly foreigner to it so I don't know much about it. And will my kernel-only implementation work with such a solution?